# Control virtual machine from script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, operating-system, system

I am trying to create a script to access the ec2 of aws from a script. At first, I used:

```
os.system('ssh -i "projectKey.pem" ubuntu@' + IP)
os.system("sudo bash")
os.system("apt-get update")
```

when it accesses the remote server, it does not run anything. When I exit, it tries to update in my own computer, is there any way to control the remote server from the script?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: what I want here to take control the terminal of virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to do what you want would be saving your `apt-get update` and other commands if you need as a script file e.g. script.sh and run it as one-liner:

```
os.system('ssh -i "projectKey.pem" ubuntu@' +  IP + " bash /dev/stdin < script.sh")
```

don't forget sudo.